# NPE when extending VideoControlsMobile class

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to extend [VideoControlsMobile](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/devbrackets/android/exomedia/ui/widget/VideoControlsMobile.java) class to add some functionality to it but I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when I'm trying to use it.

The code where I use this class is :

```
MyVideoControls controls = new MyVideoControls(this);

emVideoView = (EMVideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
emVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
emVideoView.setControls(controls);

emVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
```

and the error I get is :

```
05-03 22:41:08.954 8385-8385/test.myapp.css.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: test.myapp.css.myapplication, PID: 8385
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{test.myapp.css.myapplication/test.myapp.css.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.VideoControls.setLoading(VideoControls.java:210)
  at com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.VideoControls.restartLoading(VideoControls.java:245)
  at com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.EMVideoView.setVideoURI(EMVideoView.java:379)
  at test.myapp.css.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Where line 38 in MainActivity is : `emVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));`

and the `MyVideoControls` class code is :

```
public class MyVideoControls extends VideoControlsMobile {

    private static final String TAG = "MY-VIDEOCONTROLS";

    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private boolean pausedForSeek = false;
    private boolean userInteracting = false;
    private boolean isFullScreen;
    private int originHeight;
    private Activity activity;
    private View rl_loading;
    private OnFullScreenListener onFullScreenListener;
    private View rl_top_control;
    private View iv_play_back;
    private View ib_switch_screen;
    private int dp_55;
    private int dp_70;
    private View ll_bottom_control;

    public MyVideoControls(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setup(context);
    }

    public MyVideoControls(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        setup(context);
    }    

    public MyVideoControls(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        Log.i(TAG, "MyVideoControls 333");
        setup(context);
        activity = (Activity) context;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.video_controls;
    }


    /**
     * Registers any internal listeners to perform the playback controls,
     * such as play/pause, next, and previous
     */
    @Override
    protected void registerListeners() {
        Log.i(TAG, "registerListeners ");
        playPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onPlayPauseClick();
            }
        });
        previousButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onPreviousClick();
            }
        });
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onNextClick();
            }
        });
    }




    /**
     * Updates the drawables used for the buttons to AppCompatTintDrawables
     */
    @Override
    protected void updateButtonDrawables() {
        defaultPlayDrawable = EMResourceUtil.tintList(getContext(), R.drawable.exomedia_ic_play_arrow_white, R.color.exomedia_default_controls_button_selector);

        defaultPauseDrawable = EMResourceUtil.tintList(getContext(), R.drawable.exomedia_ic_pause_white, R.color.exomedia_default_controls_button_selector);
        playPauseButton.setImageDrawable(defaultPlayDrawable);

        defaultPreviousDrawable = EMResourceUtil.tintList(getContext(), R.drawable.exomedia_ic_skip_previous_white, R.color.exomedia_default_controls_button_selector);
        previousButton.setImageDrawable(defaultPreviousDrawable);

        defaultNextDrawable = EMResourceUtil.tintList(getContext(), R.drawable.exomedia_ic_skip_next_white, R.color.exomedia_default_controls_button_selector);
        nextButton.setImageDrawable(defaultNextDrawable);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the view references from the xml layout
     */
    @Override
    protected void retrieveViews() {
        rl_top_control = findViewById(R.id.rl_top_control);
        iv_play_back = findViewById(R.id.iv_play_back);
        iv_play_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isFullScreen) {
                    //quitFullScreen();
                } else {
                    activity.finish();
                   //activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_in, R.anim.slide_right_out);
                }

            }
        });
        ll_bottom_control = findViewById(R.id.ll_bottom_control);

        currentTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exomedia_controls_current_time);
        endTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exomedia_controls_end_time);
        playPauseButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.exomedia_controls_play_pause_btn);
        previousButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.exomedia_controls_previous_btn);
        nextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.exomedia_controls_next_btn);
        loadingProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.exomedia_controls_video_loading);
        controlsContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.exomedia_controls_interactive_container);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.exomedia_controls_video_seek);
        rl_loading = findViewById(R.id.rl_loading);

        ib_switch_screen = findViewById(R.id.ib_switch_screen);
        ib_switch_screen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isFullScreen) {
                    //quitFullScreen();
                } else {
                    //setFullScreen();
                }

            }
        });


    }


    /**
     * Performs any initialization steps such as retrieving views, registering listeners,
     * and updating any drawables.
     *
     * @param context The context to use for retrieving the correct layout
     */
    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) {
        View.inflate(context, getLayoutResource(), this);
        retrieveViews();

        registerListeners();
        updateButtonDrawables();

    }


    public interface OnFullScreenListener {
        void onFullScreen(boolean isFullScreen);
    }

}
```

Comment: post VideoControls.java and indicate line 210, as this is where your NPE is

Comment: @petey [VideoControls.java](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/devbrackets/android/exomedia/ui/widget/VideoControls.java)

Comment: `textContainer` is null. You should debug your app and find out why.

Comment: @Mes Try to use `textContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.exomedia_controls_text_container);` inside your `retrieveViews` method.

Comment: @AllanPereira I tried it but I still get a NPE .

Comment: please post your `video_controls` layout file